# Create row from previous and next rows if date are discontinuous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, indexing

I need to create a row if Current End date compared to Start date from next row are discontinuous by each Employee Number. The dataframe looks like this:

| Employee Number | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1999-11-29 | 2000-03-12 |
| 001 | 2000-03-13 | 2001-06-30 |
| 001 | 2001-07-01 | 2002-01-01 |
| 002 | 2000-09-18 | 2000-10-05 |
| 002 | 2000-10-06 | 2001-06-30 |
| 002 | 2004-05-01 | 2005-12-31 |
| 002 | 2008-01-01 | 2008-11-25 |

A Continuous flag column needs to identify these discontinuous values:

| Employee Number | Start Date | End Date | Continuous Flag | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1999-11-29 | 2000-03-12 | Y | 2000-03-13 is 1d after 2000-03-12 |
| 001 | 2000-03-13 | 2001-06-30 | Y | 2001-07-01 is 1d after 2001-06-30 |
| 001 | 2001-07-01 | 2002-01-01 | NaN | missing 2023-01-01 End Date row |
| 002 | 2000-09-18 | 2000-10-05 | Y | 2000-10-06 is 1d after 2000-10-05 |
| 002 | 2000-10-06 | 2001-06-30 | N | 2004-05-01 is not 1d after 2001-06-30 |
| 002 | 2004-05-01 | 2005-12-31 | N | 2008-01-01 is not 1d after 2005-12-31 |
| 002 | 2008-01-01 | 2008-11-25 | NaN | missing 2023-01-01 End Date row |

Then, for those rows that are 'N', a row needs to be inserted with the discontinuous dates to make them continuous in between rows. If there is no next row, use '2023-01-01' by default. Here is the expected output:

| Employee Number | Start Date | End Date | Continuous Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1999-11-29 | 2000-03-12 | Y |
| 001 | 2000-03-13 | 2001-06-30 | Y |
| 001 | 2001-07-01 | 2002-01-01 | Y |
| 001 | 2002-01-02 | 2023-01-01 | NaN |
| 002 | 2000-09-18 | 2000-10-05 | Y |
| 002 | 2000-10-06 | 2001-06-30 | Y |
| 002 | 2001-07-01 | 2004-04-30 | Y |
| 002 | 2004-05-01 | 2005-12-31 | Y |
| 002 | 2006-01-01 | 2007-12-31 | Y |
| 002 | 2008-01-01 | 2008-11-25 | Y |
| 002 | 2008-11-26 | 2023-01-01 | NaN |

I tried idx for loop without success

Comment: the records are DB records? are you forced to use DF?

Comment: yes, approx 60,000 rows from DB. Not forced to use DF but would like to have it on final form

Comment: There's something I don't understand: there are only 2 discontinuities in your 2nd table, but 4  rows are added... Oh I see now, 2 rows of the middle table should have been tagged N (the last and 3rd from last); please fix your examples, for this is confusing.

Comment: I would iterate over the row and use a nested dict , where the keys are Employee Number  and End Date , now in each iteration check if the  Employee Number is in dict, if no add it with end date as nested key, if Yes, check if existing keys +1 are equal to current row end date if so mark as Y

Comment: @Swifty the other 2 are final rows with '2023-01-01' as the end date

Comment: The final row for emp. 001 is tagged as N (because it needs to go to 2023-01-01, but the final row for emp. 002 isn't: this is inconsistent; and the 3rd row from the end shows a clear discontinuity with the next one, so it should be tagged N.

Comment: @Swifty Thanks, sorry for the confusion, middle table has been updated

Comment: Is your only goal to set `continuous_flag`?  If there is something else, make that clear in the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:  (Filling in gaps)

1. Create a table of all possible dates (in the desired range).  (This is easy to do on the fly in MariaDB by using a `seq_...`, but messier in MySQL.)
2. `SELECT ... FROM that-table-of-dates  LEFT JOIN your-table ON ...`

As for filling in the gaps with values before (or after) the given hole. I don't understand the goals.

Plan B:  (Simply discovering gaps)

Do a "self-join" of the table with itself.  For this you must have consecutive ids.  Since you don't have such, I am not sure what to do.

Then check whether the `(end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY)` of one row matches the `start_date` of the 'next' row.

Plan C:  (requires MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB 10.2)

Use `LAG()` (or `LEAD() windowing functions to compare a value in one row to the previous (or next) row.

This may be the simplest way to set the "continuous flag".

Be sure to check for discontinuity in EmployeeId as well as `INTERVAL 1 DAY` as mentioned above.